# How do I fix these error messages associated with setting up a WordPress child theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I did the following steps to setup my WordPress child theme; however, I am receiving these error messages:

1) created a folder called canvas-child in my themes directory
2) created a style.css file within this canvas-child directory and put the following code at the top of the .css file:

```
@import "../canvas/style.css";
/*
Theme Name: Canvas Child Theme
Theme URI: http://www.example.com/
Version: 1.0
Description: Custom Theme based on Canvas
Author: My Name
Author URI: http://www.example.com
Template: canvas
*/
```

3) Went into my WP admin and activated this child theme...however I receive these errors:

```
Warning: fopen(http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/style.css) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required in example.com/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4339

Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in example.com/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4342

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in example.com/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4345
```

Comment: Yup, that makes sense -- the first error, a 401 Authorization Required, would indicate that your style file wasn't readable. But do also take on board @stealthyninja's suggestion to move the @import below the comment block; that special comment block should be the first thing in any theme's style.css file.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I did follow @stealthyninja's suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All, I figured it out...My website was password protected with a username and password. I removed the authentication and it works fine now :) Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Move your `@import "../canvas/style.css";` to below the comment block:

```
/*
Theme Name: Canvas Child Theme
Theme URI: http://www.example.com/
Version: 1.0
Description: Custom Theme based on Canvas
Author: My Name
Author URI: http://www.example.com
Template: canvas
*/
@import "../canvas/style.css";
```

Comment: The `get_file_data` function is failing because you can't have any other data before the comment block. For further reference -- http://codex.wordpress.org/File_Header#File_Header_Specification

Comment: Indeed. Though it's a "comment", WordPress does dig into this header to grab the information from it for use on the Theme admin page, etc., so it has to be the first thing in the file and in the specified format.

Comment: On the other hand, I'm not entirely convinced that's the problem, as the error seems to suggest that the style file can't actually be read, which is a bit odd...

Comment: All, I figured it out...My website was password protected with a username and password. I removed the authentication and it works fine now :) Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use import, WP does it automatically.

Comment: I don't believe it does. From [the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes): "it **replaces** the style.css of the parent." On that page you can also see a child theme importing the parent's theme using `@import`, specifically so it picks up the parent theme's rules as a basis of its own style.

Comment: I figured it out...My website was password protected with a username and password. I removed the authentication and it works fine now :) Thank you for your help